# Starting Quests: Welcome Home not showing up?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I recently started Guild Wars 2 and I cannot seem to get the Welcome Home quest to work.  I have leveled up to level 9 doing basic environment quests but when I try to look at my personal quest, I cannot seem to activate it.  I have completed Defending Shaemoor but the Welcome Home quest only has a title without any green emblem beside it.

I watched a couple of intro videos to the game and it seems like the quest should be active at all times.

Comment: It could be that somewhat recent patches changed the level requirement for the next quest chain to level 10. They made it so you unlock a whole batch of quests every 10 levels instead of a single piece every 2 levels or so.  Try leveling to 10 and see if it helps.

Comment: All you had to do was look up [Welcome Home](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Welcome_Home) on the wiki, which says it's for level 10 (twice).

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I skimmed through some older guides and watched some older videos - they must have been made before the change.  I should have paid more attention to the Wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update on the 9th of September 2014 introduced the [new player experience](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/a-fresh-start-the-new-player-experience-in-guild-wars-2/), which changed the progression of the personal story from a [continuous experience to a discrete one](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Game_updates/2014-09-09#New_Player_Experience) (e.g. unlock story arcs every 10 levels).

Therefore, you will get both your mail and your first personal story (after the introduction) on level 10.